# Point lies inside a triangle ABC with $\measuredangle BAC=45^\circ$ and $\measuredangle ABC=30^\circ$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

A triangle $ABC$ is given with $\measuredangle BAC=45^\circ$ and $\measuredangle ABC=30^\circ.$ Point $M$ lies inside the triangle and $\measuredangle MAB=\measuredangle MBA=15^\circ.$ Find $\measuredangle BMC$.
[image]
I am not sure how to approach the problem. We can find some angles:$$\measuredangle ACB=180^\circ-45^\circ-30^\circ=105^\circ\\ \measuredangle CAM=45^\circ-15^\circ=30^\circ\\ \measuredangle MBC=30^\circ-15^\circ=15^\circ\\ \measuredangle AMB=180^\circ-2\cdot15^\circ=150^\circ.$$

I will be very grateful if we can see a solution without using trigonometry.

Comment: @KennyLau, It would be more helpful if you gave me some tips for the solution. Have a nice day!

Comment: For questions like these, use trig form of Ceva as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3988729/what-is-the-value-of-x-in-this-triangle-problem/3988765)

Comment: @cosmo5, thank you for the response! I am not sure I see it. May I ask you how the trig form will look in this problem?

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/TrigCeva.shtml

Comment: @cosmo5, I still don't see the pattern to form the theorem.

Comment: @cosmo5, also how can I find the sines of $\measuredangle ACM$ and $\measuredangle BCM$?

Comment: @IDoktrova I'm not on PC, I'll respond later. MathLover can clear your doubts. :)

Comment: @cosmo5 As per OP's later clarification, this question is from class 7th book. So I decided to add a geometric solution with a simple construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please apply Trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem.

If $\angle BCM = x$,

$\sin \angle BAM \ \sin \angle ACM \sin CBM = \sin \angle MAC \ \sin \angle MCB \ \sin \angle MBA$

$\sin 15^0 \sin (105^0-x) \sin 15^0 = \sin 30^0 \sin x \sin 15^0$

$\cos (15^0-x) \sin 15^0 = 2 \sin 15^0 \cos 15^0 \sin x$

$\sin 30^0 \cos (15^0-x)  = \cos 15^0 \sin x$

$\sin (45^0-x) + \sin (15^0+x)  = \sin (15^0+x) + \sin(x-15^0)$

$45^0-x = x-15^0 \implies x = 30^0$

So $\angle BMC = 180^0 - 30^0 - 15^0 = 135^0$.

**EDIT**: For geometric solution, see the below construction that you can use. $AN$ is angle bisector of $\angle CAM$. You can prove $\angle ANM = \angle ANC = 60^0$ and $CN = NM$. So, $\angle MCB = 30^0$. $\therefore \angle BMC = 135^0$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! What is the pastern for the trig Ceva's theorem?

Comment: You mean the pattern for it?

Comment: Yes..................

Comment: Take alternate angles made by Cevians with triangle sides. In total there are $6$ angles. So pair of three alternate angles. You can see more details in the link that cosmo5 shared.

Comment: Also can I ask you why $\measuredangle ACM=105^\circ-x$?

Comment: Yes, I see that.

Comment: But I don't see how from here $\measuredangle ACM=105^\circ-x$. $\measuredangle BCM$ isn't equal to $x$?

Comment: I assumed in the beginning that $\angle BCM = x$. So yes $\angle BCM$ is $x$.

Comment: Thank you! This is an advanced solution! It will be grateful if we can see a solution without using trigonometry, because this problem is for 7th grade math students.

Comment: In that case, even sine law may not work? let me know. I will let you know of alternatives - geometric construction? also it will be good to add such contexts in the question upfront.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120697/discussion-between-idoktorova-and-math-lover).

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution without trigonometry. The key is consider the midpoint of $BC$, which I have named $N$ in the picture below. Using the dashed lines and the observations that $|AD| = |CD| = |CN| = |DN| = |BN|$, it is easy to show that $\angle BAN = 15^{\circ}$. This means that $A$, $M$ and $N$ are colinear, and in addition that $\triangle NMB \sim \triangle NBA$. This gives the ratio $|NM| / |NB| = |NB| / |NA|$, and since $N$ was the midpoint of $BC$, we conclude that also $|NM| / |NC| = |NC| / |NA|$. This means that $\triangle NMC \sim \triangle NCA$, from which it follows that $\angle BMC = \angle BMN + \angle NMC =  30^{\circ} + 105^{\circ} = 135^{\circ}$, as desired.

A final remark: it is actually true that $|AM| = |AC|$, as follows easily from the above proof. However, I could not immediately find a solution that somehow exploits this fact, but it seems to me that it should be possible. Anyone up for it?

[image]

Comment: Nice. My geometric solution shows $AM=AC$.